# Can't boot from CD - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot

I'm tired of ubuntu now and and switching back to windows. Im gonna use the OS-Uninstaller but the problem is I can't boot from my ubuntu cd. When I installed ubuntu im quite sure I pressed F11 to choose boot from cd. Now I tried all F buttons and it just boots normal or gets to a black screen with a bunch of white text and then boots normal.

Here is my motherboard:

```
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
Manufacturer: MSI
Product Name: 870A-G46 (MS-7599)
Version: 4.0
Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Features:
    Board is a hosting board
    Board is replaceable
Location In Chassis: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Chassis Handle: 0x0003
Type: Motherboard
Contained Object Handles: 0
```

Any ideas on how I can boot from cd?

Comment: What does the motherboard manual say? Have you followed the instructions there without success? This question should probably be raised on http://serverfault.com/ , since it's about you motherboard, rather than Ubuntu.

Comment: I dont have a manual, this is not a factory built computer.

Comment: No, but a quick googling brings up the product support page, with the manual for download: https://us.msi.com/product/motherboard/support/870AG46.html#down-manual

Comment: That did not make me any wiser, I really cant get to the boot option, is there no other way to remove ubuntu/install windows?

Comment: So, which key brings up the boot menu, according to the manual? Can you try getting to the configuration screen?

Comment: There is no need for uninstalling Ubuntu before you install Windows as the Windows Installation will give you the chance to overwrite any underlying Operating Systems.

If you are having troubles booting from the Windows CD/DVD please check the configuration in the [BOOT] section of your BIOS and ensure the DVD has the highest priority.

Answer (score -1):

are you Confidence your cd is bootable iso ? you can download ubuntu iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ and then (in windows ) right click on iso file and choose burn disk image waiting for burn complete and verify disk 
for verify : 
insert disk and wait for run autoplay if you see a window like show install ubuntu this mean your disk is bootable the you can install ubuntu after restart and boot from disk